# How Exactly Geofencing for Android Works?

Tags: android, android-geofence, location-services

I am trying to implement location-aware App and trying to use Geofence APIs of Google-Play-Services. I haven't completely test it yet. But, I am curious about how exactly Google gonna send Intent to my registered service.

Because all the code for adding geofences are in client (mobile) app, if my app is being installed in 20 different devices, was it gonna be 20 different set of Geofences in Google Server or does it only be one set for all the copies of my App ?

Because all the code for adding geofences are in client (mobile) app, can I programatically control the set of Geofences among different copies of my App ?

Let's say, for one device, I programatically add Geofences. But, for another, I don't. (Eg; if Phones, I add Geofences. If Tablets, I won't). What's gonna happen when tablet user enter into a geofence ?

If tablet user won't receive Intent from Google, there has to be some point that Google knows which copies of my App to send Intent. I can't find any point that related to underlying device (such as device id) in Geofencing APIs.

If tablet user will receive Intent from Google even though the App programatically decided not to add the Geofences, it's not gonna make any sense.

For example, in GCM, only the devices which registered to Google Server with device id will receive the notification.

There has to be some points that I am missing. Let me know if you have any experience on it.
Thanks.